# How to tag an artefact in Nexus repository?

Tags: jenkins, tags, nexus

I want to tag specific artefacts in my Nexus repository and then display the list of such tagged artefacts in Jenkins pipeline as parameters. How can I tag artefacts in Nexus?

Comment: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Tagging  … but note that is a licensed feature.

Answer (score 0):

To tag an artefact you could use a curl command like :

```
curl -u userToken -X POST "https://your.nexus.url/service/rest/v1/tags/associate/tagName?repository=repoName&group=folder%2Fwhere%2Fyou%2Fwant" -H "accept: application/json"
```

Where :

- tagName is the expected tag
- repoName is your repository.
- %2F in the URL parameter is for a slash, as per URL parameter encoding rules. I tried with a "/" but that didn't work under windows.

This command will tag all artefacts in the folder.